# Cloud Storage Website Sharing Two server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cloud, cloud-hosting

I have a cloud storage website running on single server.
I want it to be like downloading and uploading on storage server and Webapp source on another server handling mysql query and other part.

But in this case bandwidth of both the server will be used equally. because, in that case, if user upload file from server who handle the website part,than the temporary files handled by php will use quota of that server and storage server too.

Is there any alternate way in which this can be done.

Can i be using node.js in this, or any other way, in which it can be done.
I do have api system for website, but that doesnt make any sense,i want directly upload my files to another server without have to connected to main server which is serving website.

I am doing this to save my money.Nothing else.Please dont say buy cheaper server, because, i want to implement this technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your application server and storage server are in the same availability zone and you transmit data between them using their private ip addresses, you will not have any bandwidth charges. If you say, put your files in s3 rather than having a second ec2 instance, as long as you have ec2 app server and s3 bucket in same region, then you will not have any bandwidth charges at all.

So, in light of this, your bandwidth usage may not be that important to you, and you will have no need to upload files directly to the storage server or s3 from client.